# How handle click event of remove item button in multiselect combobox vaadin 14

Tags: combobox, vaadin14

[image: PFA]Would like to show confirmation dialog when any of the selected items is removed from multi select combo box. We have this token remove button and its click event I would like to know how we can handle its click event in java ?

Comment: Maybe you can add a few details of what you're trying to do and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There's no Java API for the click listener of the items. However, if you want to add a confirmation step for deselection, you can use a workaround with a selection listener, as the selection event knows the previous selection set and the new selection set:

```
        MultiselectComboBox<String> multiselectComboBox = new MultiselectComboBox();
        multiselectComboBox.setLabel("Select items");
        multiselectComboBox.setItems("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4");
        multiselectComboBox.addSelectionListener(event -> {
            if (!event.isFromClient()) {
                return;
            }
            Set<String> removedSelection = event.getRemovedSelection();
            if (removedSelection.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            String itemsAsString = String.join(",", removedSelection);
            ConfirmDialog confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog();
            confirmDialog.setHeader("Are you sure you want to remove " + itemsAsString);
            confirmDialog.setConfirmButton("Ok", null);
            confirmDialog.setCancelButton("Cancel", e -> {
                multiselectComboBox.select(event.getOldSelection());
            });
            confirmDialog.open();
        });
```

This won't preserve the order of the selection, but that might be doable as well with a little bit of effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help ollitietavainen workaround is working but this will immediately remove that item from multi select combo box I mean this will not wait for ok button to be clicked maybe because we are using selection listener right ?

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes and observed that previously mentioned behavior

Comment: Then try a value change listener maybe?

Comment: getRemovedSelection method is not their in value change listener

Comment: You'll need to track the selection in the selection listener